# How can I statically detect missing @Override annotations?

Tags: java, eclipse, oop, static-analysis, overriding

Between Java 5 and Java 6, the rules regarding `@Override` annotations for methods originating in interfaces (as opposed to superclasses) were changed - before they were not allowed, but after they were.  However, they are not *required* by javac.

Some IDEs, like eclipse, can generate errors or warnings for such missing overrides.  I'm looking for any kind of static analysis tool that can detect missing overrides, so I can report/block them programmatically.

It doesn't seem like any of the big ones I'm aware of like findbugs, et al can do it - probably because `@Override` only has source retention level, so is not present in .class files on which these tools operate, and source level tools like checkstyle don't understand the full class hierarchy.

Comment: When I invoke checkstyle there is no place for a classpath.  That is fine for checkstyle checks, but how would checkstyle know my `void doStuff()` overrides your `void doStuff()` method w/out having your classes (either in the source or classpath).

Comment: Yeah exactly, so even apart from the runtime retention issue, checkstyle is just doing "local" checks on a file and probabbly couldn't pick this up.

Comment: I don't understand why the Retention is an issue.  The checker will need access to your source code and the class files of your dependencies.  It will not need access to the source code of your dependencies.  (If it found a missing `@Override` in source code that you do not have write privileges, what would you do?)

Comment: Rentention is an issue because most of those tools work on the class files.  If they use the source at all, it's just as the last step to display the issue in source format.  So if rentention is source only, then I think these tools won't ever find that issue and I can stop looking at them.  I would love to be proven wrong.

Comment: Checkstyle works on the source not on the class files.

Comment: Yup, you are right.  So my comment above should apply only to findbugs.  Doesn't look like checkstyle can detect missing overrides, except in this very limited MissingOverride case mentioned here:

http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_annotation.html

Comment: There is a check in Checkstyle validating a presence of `@Override` annotation when `{@inheritDoc}` is there: http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/annotation/MissingOverrideCheck.html. Now exactly what you need, but maybe will help a bit

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? What issues are you seeing that result from "missing" `@Override` annotations?

Comment: We want to enforce @Override annotations.  We have this error turned on in eclipse, so if you anyone checks in a problematic (missing override) function, it shows as an error.  We have an automated system which validates that every change compiles and passes some basic sanity tests before it gets checked in - but this system uses javac, and can't detect the missing Override.  So if a developer fails to notice the error in eclipse, and checks in the file, every who syncs that change has to fix it by hand locally. We want to detect these errors in our validation step, like other compiler errors.

Comment: I understand that you want to enforce this .. but why? What issue does "missing" this annotation cause?

Comment: If you mean what does it cause with our warnings settings in eclipse - it causes a compile error.

Comment: If you are asking what the point of using this annotation in the first place is, the basic idea is to avoid both inadvertent overrides (overriding methods without intending to), and failed overrides (intending to override a method, but failing because the method name, signature or something else doesn't match).

Diligently using @Override when you intend to override satisfies the second - a compile will fail if you try to override something. Eclipse's warning is needed to satisfy the first (asking you "did you intend to override?").

Comment: Also, the warning helps the second case by ensuring you actually use @Override when you intended to, since it causes a warning.

Comment: Asking "what's the issue" is the same as questioning the value of `@Override`. 

If you modify the signature of an overridden/overriding method, you've broken your code (code that would invoke your override via an interface/superclass method no longer will do so), but you will not necessarily get a compiletime warning - the purpose of `@Override` 

The default set of Checkstyle checks seems to require `@Override` only if `@Inheritdoc` is present.    IMHO, that's  suboptimal.   It should be based only on whether the method overrides a superclass method or implements an interface method.

Answer (score 3):

You can just enable a save action in Eclipse to automatically add the missing @Override annotation - see Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Save Actions > Missing Code > Add missing annotations.

Comment: Yup, but the issue is in an environment with many different IDEs and non-IDE development environments, you can't guarantee everyone will do that. My goal is to detect cases where they are missing, not change the existing development tools to ensure they are missing less.

Comment: Well, in the question you say "to prevent them from entering our code base in the first place". So I am not sure what you want.

Comment: Such a check could be done in a "pre-checkin" system which validates source before it enters the main source repository.  In any case, that part isn't really relevant so I will remove/clarify it.

I just need an automated tool that can detect these problems.

Comment: The same action is also available as a 'Clean-up' which can be executed any time - the clean up will detect all the problems and fix all of them. One person in the team who is using Eclipse can probably do this periodically - just takes a few minutes to run the cleanup.

Comment: Thanks, I'm well aware of the capabilities offered by the IDE and this is what is done today. When dealing with 1,000 developers working on the same codebase checking in missing @Overrides on a regular basis (every day), an automated solution is desirable.

Comment: Ok.. Eclipse has its own compiler (ECJ) which can be used outside the IDE as well, see http://blog.deepakazad.com/2010/05/ecj-eclipse-java-compiler.html. So you can possibly use ECJ in your build to automatically detect such things.

Answer (score 1):

You obviously need something that processes Java source code, and gives you access to the code structures and the attributes.

I understand Eclipse has some parsing machinery in JDT, and you might be able to use that.

Our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit has a full Java source parser (including attribute capture), full name and type resolution, and the ability to read many source files at once.  DMS is designed to let you build your own custom analysis tool, so you can define the conditions under which you insist the attributes be present or not.

Because DMS also provides program transformation capability, you can even define customizations rules that will modify source code where it is clear what attributes should be present.

DMS and the Java languages rules are not trivial to learn; this takes some effort to configure.  But if you really have thousands of developers,  this cost is swamped by the inability to control what they are doing, so the investment makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

[JArchitect](http://www.jarchitect.com) Could resolve your problem by using CQLinq and exceute request like this

> from t in Types where !t.HasAnnotation("Override") select t

And of course you can customize your query as you like to add other criteria.