# How to enable checkstyle's MissingOverride check?

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I have a

```
public interface Interface0 {

    void method0();
}
```

and a

```
public class Implementation0 implements Interface0 {

    public void method0() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

and I'm using the `maven-checkstyle-plugin` by declaring

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>checkstyle</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <configLocation>${basedir}/check_style.xml</configLocation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and finally I'm activating `MissingOverride` in `check_style.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
   "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.2//EN"
   "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_2.dtd">
<module name="Checker">
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="MissingOverride"/>
    </module>
</module>
```

This is the extract of my experience in many projects that all checks work fine, except for `MissingOverride` which has no effect, i.e. doesn't detect a single missing `@Override` annotation.

Comment: Readers of this question he may also want to read: [java - How can I statically detect missing @Override annotations? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043469/how-can-i-statically-detect-missing-override-annotations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of the `MissingOverride` module states:

> Verifies that the java.lang.Override annotation is present **when the
>   {@inheritDoc} javadoc tag is present.**

*[Documentation link](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_annotation.html#MissingOverride)*

In other words, its not intended to check what you want it to check - it only checks if the use of the `{@inheritDoc}` tag in the Javadoc comment is paired with an `@Override` annotation.

Comment: Checkstyle is not type aware, it is only a static analyzer. This means it only sees 1 class at a time, and doesn't know the make up of `Interface0` when it is processing `Implementation0`. This requires multi-file validation which Checkstyle doesn't currently support.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the Checkstyle [documentation](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_annotation.html#MissingOverride#MissingOverride) for `MissingOverride`, it states that you would need the `{@inheritDoc}` javadoc tag also in order for this to work, but it would only check that it's paired with the other annotation.

Try that. It works for me :)

Although, forgetting to include that would be the same as your original problem.